# slick, arrows centered only the picture-height, not picture width

Tags: css, slider, slick.js

I'm using [Slick-Slider](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/) to build sliders. The position of the arrows are inside the `picture`. But if the legend is too large, the arrows overlap the text (vertically centered). I would like to have the arrows only vertical centered over the picture. How can I build this?

Thanks for help/ideas!

### HTML:

```
<div class="mgu-basic-slider">
  <div>
    <picture>
      <source srcset="demo-ressoures/16zu9_topf_d.jpg">
      <img src="demo-ressoures/16zu9_topf_d.jpg" alt="xxx">
    </picture>
    <div class="mgu-basic-slider-caption">
      <div class="slick-legend">
        <p>Pfanne mit Deckel, Dampfeinsatz, Gargut, Gewürze Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt. Cras dapibus. Vivamus elementum semper nisi. Aenean vulputate eleifend tellus. Aenean leo ligula, porttitor eu, consequat vitae, eleifend ac, enim. Aliquam lorem ante, dapibus in, viverra quis, feugiat a, tellus. Phasellus viverra nulla ut metus varius laoreet. Quisque rutrum. Aenean imperdiet. Etiam ultricies nisi vel augue. Curabitur ullamcorpe.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="slick-counter">1/6</div>
      <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
<div>
<picture>
  <source srcset="demo-ressoures/16zu9_topf_d.jpg">
  <img src="demo-ressoures/16zu9_topf_d.jpg" alt="xxx">
</picture>
<div class="mgu-basic-slider-caption">
  <div class="slick-legend">
    <p>Pfanne mit Deckel, Dampfeinsatz, Gargut, Gewürze</p>
  </div>
  <div class="slick-counter">2/6</div>
  <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

### JS:

```
$(".mgu-basic-slider").slick({
  dots:false,
  adaptiveHeight: true,
  arrows : true,
  appendArrows: $('picture')
})
```

[image: Screenshot of Issue]

Comment: can you add a demo for your slider with above issue? i don't see any slider demo with a `legend` in referenced site

Comment: I would suggest leaving the CSS and instead change the [`appendArrows`](https://github.com/kenwheeler/slick/#settings) value to move the place that the arrows html is appended

Comment: thanks, i edit the questions with my code. I tried appendArrows but unfortunatley it doesnt work. what is wrong?

Comment: You should append your **CSS** code that applies to your question since you're facing a styling issue.

Answer (score 5):

I'd suggest my own solution here, using 2 sliders instead of 1. See this demo:

```js
$(".mgu-basic-slider-legend").slick({
  dots: false,
  arrows: false,
  adaptiveHeight: true,
  asNavFor: '.mgu-basic-slider'
});
$(".mgu-basic-slider").slick({
  dots: false,
  adaptiveHeight: true,
  arrows: true,
  asNavFor: '.mgu-basic-slider-legend'
});
```

```css
img {
  width: 100%;
}

.mgu-basic-slider .slick-next{
  right: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}

.mgu-basic-slider .slick-prev{
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.slick/1.6.0/slick.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.slick/1.6.0/slick-theme.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.slick/1.6.0/slick.min.js"></script>

<div class="mgu-basic-slider">
  <div>
    <picture>
      <source srcset="http://placehold.it/400x100">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/400x100">
    </picture>
  </div>
  <div>
    <picture>
      <source srcset="http://placehold.it/400x150">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/400x150">
    </picture>
  </div>
  <div>
    <picture>
      <source srcset="http://placehold.it/400x250">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/400x250">
    </picture>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="mgu-basic-slider-legend">
  <div>
    <div class="mgu-basic-slider-caption">
      <div class="slick-legend">
        <p>Pfanne mit Deckel, Dampfeinsatz, Gargut, Gewürze Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis,
          sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt. Cras dapibus.
          Vivamus elementum semper nisi. Aenean vulputate eleifend tellus. Aenean leo ligula, porttitor eu, consequat vitae, eleifend ac, enim. Aliquam lorem ante, dapibus in, viverra quis, feugiat a, tellus. Phasellus viverra nulla ut metus varius laoreet.
          Quisque rutrum. Aenean imperdiet. Etiam ultricies nisi vel augue. Curabitur ullamcorpe.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="slick-counter">1/6</div>
      <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div class="mgu-basic-slider-caption">
      <div class="slick-legend">
        <p>Pfanne mit Deckel, Dampfeinsatz, Gargut, Gewürze</p>
      </div>
      <div class="slick-counter">2/6</div>
      <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div class="mgu-basic-slider-caption">
      <div class="slick-legend">
        <p>Pfanne mit Deckel, Dampfeinsatz, Gargut, Gewürze</p>
      </div>
      <div class="slick-counter">2/6</div>
      <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS in this snippet is only for demo purpose, the main point is instead of using 1 slider we break them into 2 different sliders that are synchronized with each other using Slick's `asNavFor` feature. This way you can keep on using Slick as-is without having to resort to some kind of 'hack'.

Comment: It is a good approach to the solution but I think it is a style problem, is it really necessary to build a second carousel for this and use more resources? In addition, using 2 synchronized carousels has its problems. For example in mobile using the swipe function to change elements, a strange behavior appears. Only when you completely change one of the elements in one of the carousels the other is that it begins to change. They do not seem a single element and they are not perfect synchronized

Answer (score 0):

You will have to change the position of the arrow from `CSS`, it should in your `slick-theme.css` file, following the `CSS`:

```
.slick-prev, .slick-next {
  font-size: 0;
  line-height: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%; /* update the value from here as per your requirement */
  display: block;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  margin-top: -10px;
  padding: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: transparent;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  background: transparent;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A first approach can be set the `top` css property of the `.slick-next` and `slick-prev` btns manually if the container of the image has always the same height like in a card. For example, like in this example:

html:

```
 <div class="mgu-basic-slider">
    <div>
        <div class="img-wrapper">
            <img src="images/complianceMod.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="text-wrapper">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolorum earum, blanditiis totam similique natus, amet. Reprehenderit dolores vero, repudiandae blanditiis, assumenda dignissimos consectetur a voluptate libero consequatur enim. Commodi, enim.
            </p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolorum earum, blanditiis totam similique natus, amet. Reprehenderit dolores vero, repudiandae blanditiis, assumenda dignissimos consectetur a voluptate libero consequatur enim. Commodi, enim.
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div class="img-wrapper">
            <img src="images/example-608web_w608.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="text-wrapper">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. </p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div class="img-wrapper">
            <img src="images/examples-of-pestle-analysis.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="text-wrapper">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nesciunt distinctio, earum enim suscipit veniam? Ab eaque molestiae, repellendus </p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div class="img-wrapper">
            <img src="images/Optimal-solution_conceptual.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="text-wrapper">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Distinctio, corporis! Consectetur eum porro quasi cumque deserunt modi, sint voluptatibus reiciendis nisi voluptatem minus id quibusdam voluptate officiis blanditiis nam consequatur.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.mgu-basic-slider {
    width: 400px;
    margin: 0 auto;

    .slick-slide {
        .img-wrapper {
            height: 300px;
            img {
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
            }
        }
    }

    .slick-next, .slick-prev{
        top: 150px;
        z-index: 9999;
        &:before {
            color: #cecece;
            font-size: 30px;
        }
    }

    .slick-next {
        right: 25px;
    }

    .slick-prev {
        left: 25px;
    }
}
```

JS:

```
$(".mgu-basic-slider").slick({
        dots:false,
        adaptiveHeight: true,
        arrows : true,
        infinite: true,
        slidesToShow: 1,
        slidesToScroll: 1
    });
```

If is not your case and you don't want to have always the same height for all the images you can calculate this `top` property dynamically using the slick events and some jquery code like:

JS:

```
$('.mgu-basic-slider').on('afterChange', function(event, slick, direction){
          var imgHeight = $('.mgu-basic-slider .slick-current .img-wrapper').height();
          console.log('imgHeight', imgHeight);
          var top = imgHeight / 2;

          console.log('top', top);
          $('.mgu-basic-slider .slick-next').css('top', top+'px');
          $('.mgu-basic-slider .slick-prev').css('top', top+'px');
        });


          var imgHeight = $('.mgu-basic-slider .slick-current .img-wrapper').height();
          console.log('imgHeight', imgHeight);
          var top = imgHeight / 2;

          console.log('top', top);
          $('.mgu-basic-slider .slick-next').css('top', top+'px');
          $('.mgu-basic-slider .slick-prev').css('top', top+'px');
```

I hope that this idae can help you